# Google map SDK - Path not accurate

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am trying to show path between two locations but it is not accurate.

```
if(center.latitude != 0 && center.longitude != 0)
            {
            NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                   @"%@?origin=%f,%f&destination=%f,%f&sensor=true&key=%@",
                                   @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json",
                                   center.latitude,
                                   center.longitude,
                                   center1.latitude,
                                   center1.longitude,
                                   KGoogleMapServerKey];

            NSError *error;
                NSDictionary *json =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
            if(json[@"routes"] != nil && [json[@"routes"] count] > 0)
            {
                GMSPath *path =[GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:json[@"routes"][0][@"overview_polyline"][@"points"]];
                GMSPolyline *singleLine = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
                singleLine.strokeWidth = 7;
                singleLine.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:56.0/255.0 green:163.0/255.0 blue:249.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
                singleLine.map = mapViewGoogle;
            }
```

This is the path I am getting :

[image]

As you can see, the blue line (path) does not go at the destination.
How to fix this ?

Comment: I think Google does not know how to reach to the destination, because of there is no route, or there is in private area, something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your route is too long. In each response from Google Directions API number of points is limited. In your example you received N points, drew route with them and zoomed mapView to area, where only four points placed.
To display always accurate route you should after each map zooming re-calculate route (including midpoints to keep route the same).
For example, **full** route on your screen has 50 points. You are zooming the map, so only 4 points displayed (your screenshot). Now take #1 as start, #5 as finish and #2 #3 #4 as midpoints and send new request to find route for these points. You'll receive new 50 points, and with them you can draw this part of route more accurately.
[image]

Comment: This seems justified. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The point of this is that there is no route for that destination, as you can see here : [Gmap of your Example](https://www.google.it/maps/dir/Oslo,+Norvegia/Naf-huset,+Storgata+2,+0155+Oslo,+Norvegia/@59.9174397,10.7393471,14.31z/data=!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x46416e61f267f039:0x7e92605fd3231e9a!2m2!1d10.7522454!2d59.9138688!1m5!1m1!1s0x46416e627249d0b1:0xd745aebf3e08ad47!2m2!1d10.7484795!2d59.9127386)

I guess that your best bet is use the same approach that Gmaps already use, i mean using dotted/dashed polyline from the last point you get directions to the actual point.

You can find out here couple examples of out to implement thy type of polyline:

[Creating a dashed using IOS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29347922/4420152)

Comment: Well if that is true then why Google maps show the path correctly on [**web**](https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/Vju+AS,+Skreddermoen+35,+4513+Mandal,+Norway/Storgata+2,+0155+Oslo,+Norway/@59.9082978,10.7358573,13z/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x46378e55431b5435:0x306f6da1490b5f7b!2m2!1d7.4111312!2d58.0184825!1m5!1m1!1s0x46416e627216c757:0xd7785d6e9ecf2c43!2m2!1d10.7483587!2d59.9127025!3e0?hl=en) ?