# how to create a dotted polyline in Google Maps with swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I've tried this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24384209/ios-google-sdk-map-cannot-create-dotted-polylines) that has some relevant objC code, but my swift2.0 version only produces dashed (and not dotted) lines. This is my code:

```
let path = // ... I define my path here
let route = GMSPolyline(path: path)
route.strokeWidth = 4.0
let styles = [GMSStrokeStyle.solidColor(UIColor(red: 0.945, green: 0.392, blue: 0.278, alpha: 1.0)), GMSStrokeStyle.solidColor(UIColor.clearColor())]
let lengths = [15,15]
route.spans = GMSStyleSpans(route.path!, styles, lengths, GMSLengthKind(rawValue: 1)!);
route.map = m_map_view
```